# Многомерная структура данных с сложностью поиска  O(log n) или O(1)

Tags: структуры-данных, поиск

Подскажите пожауйста, существует ли такая структура данных, для хранения многомерной информации, с сложностью поиска O(log n) или O(1)?

Сложность добавления, удаления или изменения элементов не столь неважны.

Comment: Может hash-таблица? При отсутствии коллизий O(1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Смотрите в сторону [`R-tree,`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) [`R*-tree,`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree) [`Hilbert R-tree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_R-tree) и других вариаций [`Spatial Data Structures.`](http://coitweb.uncc.edu/~ras/MDB/ch4-VS.pdf)

> - Для `R-tree,` например, доказана алгоритмическая сложность операции `SEARCH,` которая выполняется за `O(lgN)` с деградацией до `O(N)` в случае перекрытия `Minimum Bounding Volumes` вставленных объектов.
> - На практике, насколько мне известно, кейс с деградацией до `O(N)` встречается не слишком часто.

- Если вам просто нужно проиндексировать некоторое количество многомерных объектов и не нужна возможность ответа на запрос *"верни мне все объекты, входящие в заданный `Minimum Bounding Volume,`"* то можете придумать для ваших объектов хэш-функцию и вставить их в **одну** хэш-таблицу.

> Однако, как мне подсказывает интуиция, речь все-таки идет не об этом.

Comment: да, интуиция вас не подвела. а что значит кейс с деградацией ? отчего будет зависет ухудшение поиска?

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно.

Comment: @cyberdream

- Ну, предположим, что вы вставили в двумерное R-tree последовательность прямоугольников от самого маленького к самому большому и таких, что каждый следующий включает в себя предыдущий (и, соответственно, все предыдущие):

`----------------------------`
`|     ----------------     |`
`|     |    ----      |     |`
`|     |   |    |     |     |`
`|     |    ----      |     |`
`|     |              |     |`
`|     ----------------     |`
`|                          |`
`----------------------------`

Comment: - Для этого случая, если вы сделаете операцию SEARCH(Самый_маленький_прямоугольник), ее алгоритмическая сложность будет O(N) независимо от способа partition'инга в R-tree, что будет худшим случаем для этой структуры данных.

- Опять же, на практике подобные разбиения случаются довольно редко, поэтому в среднем говорят про O(lgN).

Answer (score 1):

Можно как минимум включать структуры с нужной сложность поиска друг в друга. Например:

```
megamap = HashMap<Координата1, HashMap<Координата2, Значение>>()
megamap.get(X).get(Y) - получить значение
```

Если количество координат в вашей многомерной структуре фиксировано (в примере 2), то асимптотически скорость будет оставаться той же.

Answer (score 0):

нашел интересный доклад по схожей теме [ММРО - Об оптимизации поиска многомерных данных в распознавании](http://www.yourcmc.ru/wiki/ММРО_-_Об_оптимизации_поиска_многомерных_данных_в_распознавании#cite_note-p028_xtree-1)